# Please explain how $n!^{-1} * n \equiv (n - 1)!^{-1} \pmod{m}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to find $^nC_r \bmod m$, and see this relation that $n!^{-1}\cdot n \equiv (n - 1)^{-1} \pmod{m}$, but didn't get it.

Comment: What is m here? Can m be anything?

Comment: I can see it partially, $(n-1)!\equiv n-1\pmod n$ if $m$ were $n$,  then it follows logically. okay partially confusing myself.

Comment: yes m can be anything

Comment: Multiply both members by $n!$.

Comment: Should that be a factorial on the right hand side?

Comment: No @Mike, at least in mod $n$ it's equivalent to ${1\over n!}\cdot n\equiv {1\over n-1}\pmod n$ at least if treated fully like integers it's true. There's 1 catch in theory.

Comment: If $n=4$ and $m=11$, $n!=24\equiv2\pmod{11}, n!^{-1}\equiv6\pmod{11},(n-1)^{-1}=3^{-1}\equiv4\pmod{11}$  The left side is equivalent to 2.  The equivalence as written does not hold.  It makes more sense as $\frac1{n!}\times n=\frac1{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: n = 4 and m = 11
the inverse of 4! mod 11 is 6 and inverse of 3! mod 11 is 2
$6 * 4 = 24 \equiv2\pmod{11}$

Comment: @joker But the OP claims in a previous comment that it is NOT a factorial on the right hand side.  It's not $3!^{-1}$, it's $3^{-1}$.

Comment: oops!  Mistook the person who edited it for the OP.  Still, as written, there is no factorial on the right hand side.  And it appeared like that before the edits as well.